# Disabling capslock key in KDE

Tags: kde, plasma, capslock

I assigned a KDE action to caps-lock key (so that cap-lock is a hotkey for that) hoping it will be disabled (a trick working for other keys). But it was not.

Why this happens and how to find a better way to disable caplock (something more acceptable than [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmda2.jpg))?

Comment: Nice picture. I believe you are going to have to change the keyboard layout to something other than English. [Customizing keyboard layouts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Howto:%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions)

Comment: My problem is caps-lock, I think that link does not give a  solution to disable caps-lock.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2190277&page=2

Comment: @Mr.Lee I don't think gnome-tweak-tool will work in KDE.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So to System Settings, then click on "Input Devices" under "Hardware", then click "Keyboard", "Advanced".

Make sure that "Configure keyboard options" is selected. Then select Caps Lock key behavior > Caps Lock is disabled

[image]

Comment: Actually, I'm not 100% sure if it will then still be available for use as a shortcut, so double-check that.

Comment: no it will not be available. btw, I'll choose additional super in the picture.

Comment: Okay, I'm glad that will work. The other alternatives are to fiddle manually with config files, either xkb or xmodmap. These could let you set caps lock to any arbitrary key, but they are a real pain to set up, so GUI and/or presets are definitely preferred!

Comment: Was searching for "map caps lock to escape kde" and found this. Handy answer for both swapping and disabling of escape :-)

Answer (score 0):

If it is still usefull, cause this question pointed me in the right direction:
The aditional super option would trigger both the original super shortcut and the one stablished to caps lock.
So, in my case, I have a notebook laptop without numpad, so I took the aditional num lock option and it worked just fine. Anyways, just find a key that in  your keyboard doesn't exists or you'll not use.
Note that if you started to configure the shorcut before doing this and set the hotkey for "Caps Lock" then you'ld have to repeat those steps afterwards for it to detect the key function change